# i'm using location.assign() when i'm scrolling but i'm not able to go back to the previous url

Tags: javascript, url, scroll, assign

I have an issue with the 'location.assign()' with scrolling to the next page :

```js
  window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
       setTimeout(function() {
          location.assign('./index2.html')
       }, 1000)
    }
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to go to the next page, but i can't go back to './index.html',
can you help me solve this problem ?

Comment: It can be related to the fact that you do that without user's action

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so i just have to add an event listener ?

Comment: I have no idea, weird issue